# Google directions api overview polyline not working

Tags: google-maps, polyline, google-maps-static-api, google-directions-api

I'm trying to show a path from the google maps directions api on a google maps static map. The url for the directions api call looks like this:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=lübeck&destination=hamburg&key=MY_API_KEY`

I get a valid json response containing all the informations. I then want to show the encoded polyline for the path overview on a static map with this api call:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&size=860x600&path=enc:THE_ENCODED_POLYLINE
```

The static map won't show the path. I suspect that the encoded polyline returned by the directions api is malformed or incomplete. If enter the returned encoded polyline into [Googles Interactive Polyline Decoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility) it automatically add a '@' character at the end. The resulting polyline will show up on a static map, but it is not matching the directions.

I did the exact work flow with path between different cities and had no problems at all. Does anybody has any ideas what's wrong with this example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The encoded "overview_polyline" that I get from [that directions](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=l%C3%BCbeck&destination=hamburg) response:

```
orwgI}ef`AiDyA{EiCkCoBgCqAeE_CgAc@cBUaBKi@QDLBd@Al@DnBHf@zBbAtCz@t@f@D~DAtCG~NChJEvHZAlAGlCo@nDs@bCYx@IhA[@^?x@?\\k@|BJfK`@dIWvDg@fBu@|@kB`BiIxK{BjDkDvHwBlDaCtCmNxLsFhFiBmFoCeIIaCS}@k@M[\\Ov@m@pA{CbCiFrE_CrCeD|GyA|E{@hCWL}@[iCmB[k@Q{@?aAPw@Zi@d@Mj@Nh@TzIpJtG`KpGrLLRbBpDnFvOpLz^lBdGvK~\\|Pfi@bUrs@vZxdAnJr[rK~Zjc@lnApeApxCpNh^|Ox_@rT`i@`JfWxGxT|EnRxOzp@hHl[nDrUpBxT|@nUX~d@v@|zBN|Lh@lQpBd[jB|PnAzIhDhRtCfMbExN~HhTpDbInEpIdNhTxTh\\~FxKbGpNtNr]jGpOfu@fjBpIxQvHrLtSrYhYha@vPfVnFtIvDhIzTjg@fFjLdJjSp[|r@r@pAhElHhFjHtHzJxGzI|Wr]bOxRjSrWnF|F`GpFrRlP~]nZj]vYveAl}@|j@te@dFhEpD`CjKtFbP~HdZ|NpYjNt_@lRj_@zUn~@fk@~{@zi@xmAhv@lFnD`FfEtF`GlE~F`Yta@tNzStClExD`HlDhIhBpFzBhIxDpRrDpSbGb\\`DbNdCzHxDhJvFfKlS`]hd@fv@fQ~Y|GzKpClDzGvG~AhApHhEzHdCr@Nfj@lKrXtFpHdClIrE`GnElDfD`NdPtuAfcBbdAvnAhVjZbGrJjGrMpDvJ`GtThE|UvAdMv@fNNrHDrd@PrGfAxK`AtFdBpGbDpIpEjIvGvIjC`C|FlEbFtCvHjDzHlC|JpCpLdDrK|CxHrCjHbDlGhDnOpKvSvPfWbVlHrHtGnHzKvNxKpPrDfGdKrR`GdMjJxT~HhTxGdTnElPnG`WpF`WlDvQrDbTlDbV`CfVf@bLPtLIdN}@hSaE`a@cAjLc@xHi@jX]jg@u@j_A]pRCnMJtIFnG]`Fk@vCw@xBwBfDaHjGuNnMSn@{VfU{XpUiGhE_Cx@aCXmDWoDcAuJwEaFoEgHiGqFiFgL}JwFyDeCwA}D{CcEuCyBmAaAYu@b@q@hBeEnMyAbGuAjIcAnH}AfLmEfRiFrS}A~CyF`F_AlBi@vBgAbIAhCBtEGpTE|@K~@m@Gw@Ds@I_Da@oB@mIxBwClAuA|AqCbEwFpK}BjFSd@ZPh@`@~@dAtL`UtChG`@hBzAFl@w@f@s@R^j@fA`@~@e@`Ac@l@E?
```

Has double encoded backslashes.  To work in the request for a static map, the `\\` needs to be translated to `\`

[image: static map]

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/odf5cs3m/)