# Google Maps API - Directions giving "overview" polyline makes no sense

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the directions api to get best route between `x` waypoints using the `Google Maps API`. My call is something like that:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?key=MY_KEY&origin=Exeter%2C+UK&destination=London&region=uk&waypoints=optimize:true|52.80443%2C1.3974969999999303|51.33700547604255%2C-2.5970759440972415|50.430475%2C-4.305309999999963`

Which returns results that seem okay (all the driving instructions). However, it also returns an overview polyline, that I want to display on my website. But whenever I decode it (whether it's on my website or using their [Polyline Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility)) it is showing some weird lines, that do not seem to correspond to the route very well (it's got the right starting point but does not show the route and at some points it moves very far off in a straight line). For example:

[image: Incorrect Polyline]

This is the polyline I get for a route for the request above. As you can see it's got lots of lines navigating around the water...

In my website I display the poly like that (but in their polyline tool I get the same line):

```
var decodedPath = google.maps.geometry.encoding.decodePath("<?=$response->routes[0]->overview_polyline->points?>");
var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({
                  path: decodedPath,
                  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                  strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                  strokeWeight: 3,
                  map: map
           });
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the proper polylines to display the outline of the actual route?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google directions api overview polyline not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42073004/google-directions-api-overview-polyline-not-working)

Comment: You need to undo the escaping (apparently): [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/odf5cs3m/1/) (removed the escaped "\" (backslashes))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The response I get from the service for [your request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Exeter%2C+UK&destination=London&region=uk&waypoints=optimize:true%7C52.80443%2C1.3974969999999303%7C51.33700547604255%2C-2.5970759440972415%7C50.430475%2C-4.305309999999963) is:

```
"overview_polyline" : {
  "points" :
  "e}ptHdgqTlsAbZv_ApHxuAclChkBncCxhBnk@n_AzrBnmDvoFh~CruD`uMpnXltBlc@bmA~{AdhHhlCzpErzKp}@jjN|a@rsLnPjcGqoApjCww@|kGkoAlcIkU|uLaaAlsEe]b{Bpe@waBy\\awD|u@ekCvu@svJbbD_tQfc@krL{k@usMqMsrG{vAwfF}aGokJwgDkv@ibCq`CkmByz@amC_gFytDevJ_xD{yG{qEkkEg}B_`EkcCwdAymAqcCk`BmqGebJ_pBogCvOajDkwBqtGkyHcgMkrE_zIabc@ar@}wIalDs_H{zKykJgrGkdFqhCoKsaFf^ceJwyDukBypAyiB_sGgjCmjJw_DklB_fBqhDtVunHbpA_aK|p@kdEixBomFqjA_l@kHcjCwhAygGfQcnFirBsvBaaBk_F}SuxDks@w|A{tDjXcaH{bF_mDm|Aox@ufIcv@gmFbu@gtLm[aiS{lEerYuiAqbGx{@{mGprBkaSplBkhXnqG_yTjsBmxGtNuyIcYayRq}@utO`T}hThxAw_InjC}sGncA}`Kau@}iF{rAqlNsmKetVupAicNrqAmpKhcAiuBsb@yoDgS{{FwuAbNgzDCgdAldCc{ClnAkzEct@wkHcoEk{AigDywBu}BsvBi`CePieEt[oiRia@}rC`tA{dDpaBa~GzM}xXlc@esPshA_cL|x@_wD_iAurBgsImM{eLohGcxC{|@caD{F}dEgoCu|D}d@szI~wCmuMbz@kaBeJkjC_vA}yH_wDseE{uJwxHyzDkzEapIc\\g_JejIyaMgeJmu[_wBc}Huu@ydBkgBob@_`AcbJmhEyrZ}cC{tFe|EkaI_hDclP_iCqfE{eAwxEe{Aa}JjiAidE{yCqlKkaBaaLmaCsaA{fAg|AoeBtx@cNxHaeCzu@{{A{kAg_@ucAmxEefDo{AsSajAr}AqxCjyFhbCgbFnuAgoBnsAvNncF~xC|f@loA`pCheDlyAhmBxx@{Jvs@}`Abo@hx@ba@pKxzAko@zuAf~ElgDphK{QpyEak@xzC~eB|{GnfApdFfcCfvDnqDzjQhgEr}Gj~C~dHf{Dh|XddAj|J`zBrp@`h@dxErwDvpJflEplQ~uCtgFxgDbuDfyAxrI`sC`zIdhGfxHpkD|{AxhClrG|oGznEpxHprCliG}u@nvFop@hgDo`A~~H}XteEfuCzeH|cA`zKtrF|bCtn@zwEsOr|HxxGjrFtiHlyBhv@xgEg}CxnCmf@hvAzlAlkAzfNgFtnIvIhsI"
```

There are two escaped backslashes ("\") in there, they need to be "un-escaped":

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/odf5cs3m/1/)

[image: screenshot of resulting static map]

[live example](http://www.geocodezip.com/SO_20170920_staticmap.html)